# Using Clonezill/DRBL DHCP as main DHCP server

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, clonezilla, drbl

Right now in my department we are running a DHCP server on some older hardware that is looking like it might fail soon(ish) and is also running CentOS 4. We'd like to upgrade to a new DHCP server but we are also in the process of updating our Clonezilla/DRBL server. We'd like to update to Ubunutu and run both DHCP and Clonezilla on the same server. I was wondering if there was any issue with running a Clonezilla/DRBL server as the main DHCP server for a number of subnets or if that could cause some problems down the line.

Answer (score 0):

I have never utilized CentOS to run DHCP, but I suppose if the function is there it can be utilized for your network.

To be honest, DHCP is usually found in two places; in your firewall or on your domain controller. Do you not have a DC for the network?

Comment: We have a DHCP server that serves addresses centrally but it also points to a central imaging server that is WDS based. We require the ability to image dual boot systems which (as far as I know) WDS cannot do. Because of this we currently run our own DHCP server and a DRBL server that serves to computer that are PXE booting.